# How to search text in multiple Powerpoint and PDF files together on windows?

Tags: windows, search, pdf, powerpoint

I have several ppt and pdf files with similar contents and I want to search them together. Is there any application or simple technique available for that? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8):

Windows Search might work but learning to use it effectively is a job in itself.

Try Agent Ransack, assuming a Windows computer.  It's free and far easier to use than Win search.  And is available for pretty much any version of Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Windows Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Search) and make sure you have the [PDF IFilter](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=2611) installed.

Answer (score 1):

> Try Agent Ransack, assuming a Windows computer. It's free and far
>   easier to use than Win search. And is available for pretty much any
>   version of Windows.

Agent Ransack works really well for finding .ppt contents. I've used it to find which of several hundred .ppt files in a folder had comments (search for commenter's handle (usually their initials) +  á,  as in ABCá

[Sample search box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaaZM.jpg)

Thanks to Steve Rindsberg for pointing me to this useful software. I'd tried Windows search and a couple of PowerPoint freeware programs, but Agent Ransack did the job and saved me manually searching multiple .ppt files.

Comment: Aaaannnd take my upvote. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

[FileLocater](https://www.mythicsoft.com/filelocatorpro/download/) is free to use for personal use. You can search in ppt, pdf, zip files.

Answer (score 0):

For PDF's, you can use Adobe Acrobat Reader to search multiple PDF files for text. Just:

- Open Acrobat Reader
- Select [File]->[Advanced Search]
- Select "All PDF Documents in"
- In the drop down menus, select "Browse for Location ..." and select the top level directory in the hierarchy you'd like to search.

[image]